# Import a security certificate with Firefox add-on

Tags: firefox, certificate

With Firefox's new WebExtension API, I have certificates that are no longer valid, due to their Legacy status. Does anyone know the basic framework for importing a certificate via a Firefox extension?

Thank you in advance!